# Not able to install Nautilus Terminal

Tags: centos, gnome, nautilus

I am using centOS Release 6.4(Final) and GNOME 2.28.2. System information is

```
Linux localhost 2.6.32-358.11.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jun 12 03:34:52 
UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I downloaded Nautilus Terminal sources from [here](http://projects.flogisoft.com/nautilus-terminal/download/). I am getting following message.

```
[root@localhost nautilus-terminal_1.0_src]# ./install.sh -i

:: Checking the Runtime Dependencies...

  > Python (>= 2.6)                                                      [ OK ]
  > PyGObject                                                            [ OK ]
  > GObject Introspection (and Gtk)                                      [MISS]
  > VTE                                                                  [MISS]
  > Nautilus Python (>= 1.0)                                             [MISS]
  > Nautilus (>= 3.0)                                                    [ OK ]
E: Some dependencies are missing.
```

Which packages do I have to install and why doesn't it resolve on it's own?

Comment: Did you noticed that `[MISS]` output ? It will not resolve on it's own cause you are not using yum or any other package manager

Comment: What packages do I have to install now manually?

Comment: a. PyGObject b. GObject Introspection (and Gtk) c. VTE  For version,you can check that in install.sh file

Comment: @AniketThakur try to use `yum whatprovides *gobject-introspection*` to see if it's there. This command can be used for other dependencies too. `yum whatprovides packagename` is used to see what package provides what library etc.